# Access Google Cloud Print in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-print

Is there any way to access Google Cloud Print in android?

Provide any reference tutorial or link for that,

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following link helps you to integrate Google Cloud Print in android.

[Google Cloud Print Integration in Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android)